# Hibernate annotation for base java class

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I would like to put into db a class that have java.awt.geom.Point2D field. Is it possible?

Here is my code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_class_table")
public class MyClass {
  private String aliasId;

  private Point2D field;

  public Point2D getField() {
    return field;
  }

  public void setFieldPoint2D field) {
    this.field = field;
  }

  public String getAliasId() {
    return aliasId;
  }

  public void setAliasId(String aliasId) {
    this.aliasId = aliasId;
  }
}
```

And the reason of the exception which is thrown:

Could not determine type for: java.awt.geom.Point2D, at table: my_class_table, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(field)]

Of course, the reason is quite obvious. My question is: how should I annotate the class to be able to use a field of Point2D class? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for response. Unfortunatelly `java.awt.Point` class uses `Integer`, so it is useless in my case. The easiest way to solve it would be to use `Point2D.Double` which implements `Serializable` (but definition of [UserType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom-ut) or [CompositeUserType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom-cut) is more convenient if you don't want to change class definition). So, the simple solution:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_class_table")
public class MyClass {
  private String aliasId;

  private Point2D.Double field;

  public Point2D.Double getField() {
    return field;
  }

  public void setField(Point2D.Double field) {
    this.field = field;
  }

  public String getAliasId() {
    return aliasId;
  }

  public void setAliasId(String aliasId) {
    this.aliasId = aliasId;
  }
}
```

But my final goal was to create a class with ordered list of points. If anybody is interested here is an example of the class representing line:

```
@Entity
public class Line {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idDb", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="points_table", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="idDb"))
    @IndexColumn(name = "idx")
    @Column(name="point_val")
    private List<Point2D.Double> points = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Point2D.Double> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(List<Point2D.Double> points) {
        this.points = points;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a `java.awt.Point` that extends `Point2D` and is a `Serializable` class. This way hibernate will automatically map it with `SerializableType` and you don't need to do anything more. The `point` object will be saved in its serialized form in a `blob` database table column.

You have also the option to define a custom hibernate type for the `Point2D` class. [Here is a link](http://dzone.com/articles/annotating-custom-types) of how to define a custom hibernate type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add annotations to existing classes.

But you [can define a `CompositeUserType`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom-cut) to tell Hibernate how to map a `Point2D`.